# What does the `in` keyword do in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I know how to use it, but I cannot find any explanation on it in docs. I'd like an accurate definition so that I could understand it better.

Edit: I mean the `in` used in mapped types, not the js operator.

Answer (score 127, accepted):

This is the standard `in` JavaScript operator. You can read more documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#in), but the short story is

> The in operator returns true if the specified property is in the specified object. The syntax is:
>
> ```
> propNameOrNumber in objectName
> ```
>
> where `propNameOrNumber` is a string or numeric expression representing a property name or array index, and `objectName` is the name of an object.

In Typescript the `in` operator also acts as a type guard as described [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10485)

```
interface A {
  x: number;
}
interface B {
  y: string;
}

let q: A | B = ...;
if ('x' in q) {
  // q: A
} else {
  // q: B
}
```

---

**Edit**

An alternative meaning of `in` in typescript is in mapped type definition. You can read about them in the [handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) or in the [pull request](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/12114). The `in` keyword is used there as part of the syntax to iterate over all the items in a union of keys.

```
interface Person {
    name: string;
    age: number;
}
type Partial<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]?: T[P]; // P will be each key of T
}
type PersonPartial = Partial<Person>; // same as { name?: string;  age?: number; }
```

Comment: It's possible that OP refers to https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types . The question isn't specific enough.

Comment: @estus yes it's possible you are right.. I did not imediately think of it. OP should clarify ideally with a code example. You mind if I add this alternative to my answer or do you want to provide an alternative answer of your own?

Comment: Yes, please, add it to the answer for consistency. I honestly don't remember when it was introduced. Typescript-specific features are inconsistently documented because the thing that's called 'documentation' is basically a guide.

Comment: @jddxf  I added the alternative usage of `in`

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir "The in keyword is used there as part of the syntax to iterate over all the items in a union of keys", exactly.

Comment: @estus I've suspected that this isn't documented. Thanks for confirming this.

Comment: @jddxf The extend of the documentation is the handbook and the PR request .. not a lot I know, but the links are in the answer. Do you have any specific questions about it ?

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir nope, I just want a definition.

Comment: @jddxf I am still confused. In fact, `[P in string]` or even `[P in number]` are also valid mapped types, and they are not anything iterating over some union type.

Comment: @weakish yeah, the compiler cheats there a little bit and creates an index signature for those. Conceptually you can think of `string` as the union of all possible string literal types (so basically an infinite union) so the explanation still holds in this limit case. (same for `number` it is the union of all possible number literal types)

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir it is looks like `in` operator no more acts as a typeguard. Please see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66163352/why-is-this-objects-type-resolving-to-one-side-of-a-type-union

Comment: a better javascript In documentation here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in

Answer (score 2):

A minimal example of the convenience of mapped types in Typescript (`in` keyword) even without the use of Generics:

```
type IdType = 'id1' | 'id2' | 'id3';
const ids: {
    [id in IdType]?: string // To make all 3 keys required remove ?
} = {
    'id1': 'myValue1',
    'id2': 'myValue2'
}
// Usage:
const myId = ids['id1'];
console.log(myId); // Prints 'myValue1'
```

The previous is equivalent to:

```
const ids: {
    'id1'?: string,
    'id2'?: string,
    'id3'?: string
} = {
    'id1': 'myValue1',
    'id2': 'myValue2'
}
```

#### When is it useful outside of Generics?

The minimal example for the `in` keyword might not seem so useful, but the situation changes when you have a big number of keys that you need as object properties or if you need the ids as runtime values on an array and not only as types, and you want that array to be the single source of truth. A more elaborate example that illustrates the mentioned use-case:

Suppose you have an array of allowed properties for an object, which could actually be very big:

```
const NETWORK_TYPES = ['devnet', 'testnet', 'mainnet'] as const;
```

You can build a type for that like this:

```
export type NetworkType = typeof NETWORK_TYPES[number];
```

Then you will be able to define an object that has these network types as properties like this with the `in` keyword:

```
const networks: {
    [key in NetworkType]?: string // To make all 3 networks required remove ?
} = {
    'devnet': 'myDevnetObject',
    'testnet': 'myTestnetObject'
}
// Usage:
const network = networks['devnet'];
console.log(network); // Prints 'myDevnetObject'
```