# How to create an Array Object

Tags: angular

In the below code If I would like to add an Placeholder for `"e"`, how can I do that in typescript. I need to check if this Placeholder has `"e"` if not I need to add `"e":"300"` to the below . The Below PlaceHolderValues comes from an JSON Object.

```
"placeHolderValues": {
      "a": "EUR",
      "b": "150M",
      "c": "EUR",
      "d": "150M"
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50214731/what-does-the-in-keyword-do-in-typescript

Comment: `if (!placeHolderValues.e) placeHolderValues.e=300;`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code :

```js
var placeHolderValues = { "a": "EUR", "b": "150M", "c": "EUR", "d": "150M" }
var checkIfeExists = Object.keys(placeHolderValues).find(p =>p == "e");

if(typeof checkIfeExists === "undefined")
{
    placeHolderValues["e"]="300"
}
console.log(placeHolderValues)
```

First of all, check if placeHolderValues contatins e.
if checkIfeExists does not exists.Add new Key "e" and value "300"

Comment: Here ofr me PlaceHolder is coming as NULL from JSON. then how can I add

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: From Json object PlaceHoldervalues will come as NULL  i.e "PlaceHolderValues":null. Now in the type script i Need to add the values to it like this  placeHolderValues = { "a": "EUR", "b": "150M", "c": "EUR", "d": "150M" }

Comment: then use object.assign to fill the values as wanted.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Answer (score 0):

I just write a simple `if condition` code in `typescript`. Try this I hope it'll help you out. Thanks

```
placeHolderValues: object = {
  "a": "EUR",
  "b": "150M",
  "c": "EUR",
  "d": "150M"
};

if(typeof this.placeHolderValues['e'] === 'undefined') {
  this.placeHolderValues['e'] = 300;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can  use `Object.assign()` to copy the values of all enumerable own properties from one or more source objects to a target object. It will return the target object.

That means anything that was not available on original object will be added in new ly returned object and any existing property will be updated.

```js
var placeHolderValues = { "a": "EUR", "b": "150M", "c": "EUR", "d": "150M" }

placeHolderValues = Object.assign(placeHolderValues, {"e":"300"}) ;

console.log(placeHolderValues);
```