# Why is this object's type resolving to one side of a type union?

Tags: typescript

See this [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=2&ssl=20&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChkHIBGcUAXMgM5hSgDmA3LgL665gCeADigEKnIAvGkzIAZDnyESALwrVaIRizYJ0Iasi5R0AEwCuSXpgA2EOCCHIAFAEohAPmQBZOGAAWAOigXd6ALZ2yE4ADJ4ArEy4ahpgyOhEAFYUGFgAPsj8UFZ4hMSkFADksoUANFIEnlXW2nqGEMboZhZBYhK5edJwcsjFpIUVyMy2KrjAMDZ9MoXIoPFJ9h0EMZRNEJ4m6HTWCYkjrEA).

Why on line 18 has `obj` already resolved as `Foo`, which causes it to then be of type `never` on line nineteen? It seems like at that point in the code it should very much still be `Foo | Bar`.

Comment: It is because `in` is a typeguard. See this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50214731/what-does-the-in-keyword-do-in-typescript

Comment: I know `in` is a typeguard, but it is resolving to the entirely wrong type.

Comment: Specifically, `"baz" in obj` should cause it to be type `Bar` but it's become type `Foo` before the type check is even done. Then in the condition it is typed as `never`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After seeing that this behavior was different a few versions of Typescript ago (3.7.5), and deciding it seemed like a bug, I opened an issue on their issue tracker here: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42771

They have just labeled it as a bug as well, so for now I guess I'll mark this as answered with the answer being, "It's not working as intended."

Answer (score 0):

Because `Math.random()` can be known only in runtime, TS is unable to make decision about a type.

So I think TS just don't takes into account `Bar` type at all. That's why you have `never`.

Further more, TS plays bad with `spread operator`.

But I'm not convinced yet :)

I was wrong in my comment. TS `in` operator behavied like a typeguard, but since TS 3.8.3 it is not typeguard anymore:

```js
// TS 3.7.5
interface Foo {
    bar: string;
}

type Bar = Foo & {
    baz: string;
}

const produceBoolean = () => Math.random() > 0.5;

const obj:Foo|Bar = {
    bar: 'baz',
    ...(produceBoolean() && {
        baz: 'bar'
    })
}

if ('baz' in obj) {
    console.log(obj) // Bar
}

if ('bar' in obj) {
    console.log(obj) // Foo | Bar
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=2&ts=3.7.5&ssl=24&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChkHIBGcUAXMgM5hSgDmA3LgL665gCeADigEKnIAvGkzIAZDnyESALwrVaIRizYJ0Iasi5R0AEwCuSXpgA2EOCCHIAFAEohAPmQBZOGAAWAOigXd6ALZ2yE4ADJ4ArEy4ahpgyOhEAFZkGOgAPvxQVniExKQUAOSyBQA0UgSeldbaeoYQxuhmFkFiEjm50nByyEWkBeXIzLYquMAwNr0yBcig8Un27QQxlI0QnibodNYJifYA9HvImSNjEyRQ07M7CwPLq%20ub2-PIByJYaUekLEA)

```js
//TS 3.8.3

interface Foo {
    bar: string;
}

type Bar = Foo & {
    baz: string;
}

const produceBoolean = () => Math.random() > 0.5;

const obj:Foo|Bar = {
    bar: 'baz',
    ...(produceBoolean() && {
        baz: 'bar'
    })
}

if ('baz' in obj) {
    console.log(obj) // never
}

if ('bar' in obj) {
    console.log(obj) // Foo
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=2&ts=3.8.3#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChkHIBGcUAXMgM5hSgDmA3LgL665gCeADigEKnIAvGkzIAZDnyESALwrVaIRizYJ0Iasi5R0AEwCuSXpgA2EOCCHIAFAEohAPmQBZOGAAWAOigXd6ALZ2yE4ADJ4ArEy4ahpgyOhEAFZkGOgAPvxQVniExKQUAOSyBQA0UgSeldbaeoYQxuhmFkFiEjm50nByyEWkBeXIzLYquMAwNr0yBcig8Un27QQxlI0QnibodNYJifYA9HvIIBAAbtAjYxMkUNOzOwsDy6vrm9vzyAci6CxAA)

I don't understand why they made such a decision.

Further more, if you remove explicit typing:

```js
interface Foo {
    bar: string;
}

type Bar = Foo & {
    baz: string;
}

const produceBoolean = () => Math.random() > 0.5;

const obj = {
    bar: 'baz',
    ...(produceBoolean() && {
        baz: 'bar'
    })
}

if ('baz' in obj) {
    console.log(obj) // baz is still optional
}
```

`baz` property will be still optional.

I think the reason is the same as `Object.keys()` always returns `string[]` instead of expected `keyof T` - because of mutability

Feel free to criticize me

Comment: I'm not quite convinced about `Math.random`, it is true that the value it will produce will not be known until runtime, but the compiler can be confident that the function will always produce a boolean either way. That means it should be able to know it can be one or the other. later in the code.

The difference in behavior in earlier Typescript versions is an interesting point though.

Comment: I wrote my answer not because I'm pretend it is fully correct, just wanted to show the difference between earlier versions. I will try to dig deeper )

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I appreciate your efforts!

Answer (score 0):

Your type `Bar` is defined as a subtype of `Foo`, so the union `Foo | Bar` is actually just equivalent to `Foo`. By analogy, if outside your house there is either a tree or an oak tree, then more simply we can just say there is a tree.

Comment: Could you possibly explain why this behavior seems different in Typescript 3.7.5, versus the version I have the playground set to? You can test it out at the same link and change the version if you have the time.

Comment: I don't know what change in Typescript causes the difference, but `never` in the more recent version is clearly incorrect; I see you've reported it on the issue tracker, which seems to be the right call.