# how do I access to the key from union interface in typescript

Tags: typescript

I added a package which has type definition like this:

```js
interface DataA {
  keyA: string;
}
interface DataB {
  keyB: string;
}

type Data = DataA | DataB
```

And I'm trying to make a function which is:

```js
type GetMyKey = (data: Data) => string
const getMyKey: GetMyKey = (data) => data.keyA || data.keyB
```

And this function makes Typescript Errors, which says that there's no `keyA` in `DataB`, and no `keyB` in `DataA`

```
Property 'keyA' does not exist on type 'Data'.
  Property 'keyA' does not exist on type 'DataB'.ts(2339)

Property 'keyB' does not exist on type 'Data'.
  Property 'keyB' does not exist on type 'DataA'.ts(2339)
```

I think I have to do type narrowing in my function but I don't have any clue how should I do.

Comment: Have you tried? type GetMyKey = (data: DataA | DataB) => string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found answer by myself.

### By using `in` keyword

https://stackoverflow.com/a/50214853/6661359

```js
const getMyKey: GetMyKey = (data) => {
  return ('keyA' in data) ? data.keyA : data.keyB
}
```

### By using type predicates (aka. type guard)

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates

```js
const isDataA = (data: Data): data is DataA => {
  return (data as DataA).keyA !== undefined
}

const getMyKey: GetMyKey = (data) => {
  return (isDataA(data)) ? data.keyA : data.keyB
}
```

Comment: Wow, you found this yourself!